# Jenkins not able to execute script

Tags: jenkins

I tried to execute a script

```
./script.sh
```

from normal terminal window this works.
Same script i call from jenkins execute shell

```
echo "start"
./script.sh
echo "end"
```

Then end is never printed it gives a build failure while executing the script itself.
Anything which I may be missing

Comment: check your script location and Jenkins config

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you cd to the workspace directory before calling the shell script shell.sh. Use the cd command with Jenin's workspace environment variable. (After the 'echo start' line.)

If you want to be able to run the same script in Jenkins and outside of Jenkins, then you can delect if the workspace environment variable returns a value, if so cd to it, if not, ignore it.